# Refresh an api query if the dict is empy in Python

Tags: python, json, loops, request

im trying to make a method who provides the following functionality:
The function receives 2 parameters: type and effort.
type must be a string from the set ["education", "recreational", "social", "diy", "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork"] type.
If another string is passed, an exception of type ValueError shall be thrown.
"effort" defines how much effort the activity should take (float between 0 and 1, 0 is least effort).
This range of numbers does not need to be checked.
The function should then use the Brd API to query for a random activity with the given type (parameter "type") and effort (parameter "accessibility"). The query must contain the passed values "type" and "effort" for this purpose.
The query is repeated until the found activity contains a link (field "link") and this value is not empty.
The return value of the method is a tuple consisting of: Name of the activity ("activity"), the type ("type"), the link ("link") and the effort ("accessibility") in exactly this order.

My problem now is that the method doesnt reload if the query "link" is empty. The method needs to run until "link" isnt empty anymore.

````
import requests

def vorschlagen(typ,aufwand):
    url=f"http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type={typ}&?accessiblity={aufwand}"
    data=requests.get(url).json()
    print(url)
    print (len(data["link"]))
    while len(data["link"])==0:
        data=requests.get(url).json()
        link=(data["link"])
        name=(data["activity"])
        typ=(data["type"])
        if typ!=["education", "recreational", "social", "diy", "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork"]:
            ValueError
        aufwand=(data["accessibility"])
        print("Aktivität :",name)
        print("Art der Aktivität (TYP) :",typ)
        print("Link :",link)
        print("Aufwand :",aufwand)
        return (name),(typ),(link),(aufwand)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement must be placed outside the `while` loop:

```
import requests

def vorschlagen(typ,aufwand):
    url=f"http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type={typ}&?accessiblity={aufwand}"
    data=requests.get(url).json()
    print(url)
    print (len(data["link"]))
    while len(data["link"])==0:
        data=requests.get(url).json()
        link=(data["link"])
        name=(data["activity"])
        typ=(data["type"])
        if typ!=["education", "recreational", "social", "diy", "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork"]:
            ValueError
        aufwand=(data["accessibility"])
        print("Aktivität :",name)
        print("Art der Aktivität (TYP) :",typ)
        print("Link :",link)
        print("Aufwand :",aufwand)
    return (name),(typ),(link),(aufwand)
```

**UPDATE**

To answer your comment:

```
import requests

def vorschlagen(typ,aufwand):
    if typ not in ["education", "recreational", "social", "diy", "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork"]:
        raise ValueError("invalid argument typ")

    url=f"http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type={typ}&?accessiblity={aufwand}"

    while True:
        
        data=requests.get(url).json()
        link=(data["link"])
        name=(data["activity"])
        typ=(data["type"])
        aufwand=(data["accessibility"])
        
        print("Aktivität :",name)
        print("Art der Aktivität (TYP) :",typ)
        print("Link :",link)
        print("len data[link]:", len(link))
        print("Aufwand :",aufwand)
        
        if len(data["link"]) > 0:
            return (name),(typ),(link),(aufwand)
```

Comment: Oh man, Thank u . Another problem is that if i enter false keys i get an KeyError. Could u help me to get a solution? I only want to accept the keys in the brackets like ""education", "recreational", "social", "diy", "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork".

Comment: I report the main issues in your code:

- to raise the `ValueError` exception, you have to use the` raise` statement;

- the first GET request, and eventually, the one at the first iteration in the while loop, `requests.get (url).json ()` are made before checking the allowed values of `typ`.

Comment: check out the update in the answer, if that's what you want ;)

Comment: Check out the "Update" section in my answer.
I take this opportunity to tell you that you should check the logic of the function ... especially updating the value of the `aufwand` and `typ` variables in the `while` loop

Comment: Now i got a runtime error : "%d format: a number is required, not str" what is meant by that?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error ... please open a new question with the code you are using and the full stack trace error

Comment: Ok i did that now.